# What is a textViewResourceId?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I've been trying to figure how the ArrayAdapter class can be used, and from the docs : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html, I see the constructor expects an integer called textViewResourceId.

What is this exactly?

Edit:
From a little more research and the answers here, it looks like it must be the id of a TextView that I defined in the xml file that contains the interface code. But I saw this example here:

`ArrAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArrayList)`

So how can android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 be used here? What does this mean really? I am only familiar with using R.id.idOfMyViewHere

Comment: show your some code, what you are trying and what happen?

Comment: @CapDroid: Can you please see the edit on the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is the id of the `textview` in which the adapter will update the info you will provide. You can use `textview` provided by android:

```
android.R.id.text1
```

for instance. Or you can provide your own `textView` whit your custom id

Edit

change:

```
ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myArrayList)
```

with

```
ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.id.text1,myArrayList)
```

Answer (score 6):

**android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1** is default layout if you want to use your layout then you can also use it like

**`new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, layout_id, textview_id, items);`**

Comment: what is the difference between `layout_id` and `textview_id`? can you explain the use and difference?

Answer (score 1):

textViewResourceId is an ID to a specific layout. To reference that id you make use of the format R.layout.* .

R.layout.* are the layouts that you have created found in your res/layout folder. So if you have a xml layout file in your res/layout/ folder named "my_list_item.xml" of whatever layout format you want, then you can use that as your textViewResourceId (not necessarily a TextView).

If you don't want to create your own layout, you can make use of the built in layouts found in your android-sdk directory, (in my case its C:\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\data\res\layout). You reference those built-in layouts through android.R.layout.* (notice I started it with "android"). So if I want to use the built in simple_list_item_1.xml then I can reference that using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.

R.layout.* <---own layout 
android.R.layout.* <--- built in Android layouts

Some popular layouts:
android.R.simple_list_item_1
simple_list_item_2.xml
etc.

Answer (score 0):

from the docs:

> A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects. By default this class expects that the provided resource id references a single TextView.

simply, it default is bind to the textView, and the text view is

> The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated