# What is resource:0 doing?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I didn't understand what is the use of 0 here.
What exactly it is doing?

```
public WordAdapter(Activity nmbersActivity, ArrayList<Word> word) {
    super(nmbersActivity,0,word);
}
```

And i have check the documentation and can't find exactly what it is.

In the implementaion this is the code.

```
public ArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
        @NonNull List<T> objects) {
    this(context, resource, 0, objects);
}
```

Comment: if you are extending ArrayAdapter<String>, 0 is for textViewResourceId and you should change it with correct Id, `(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects)`

Comment: @Farrokh but it is working properly? And what is a textViewResourceId.Can you elaborate?

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025773/what-is-a-textviewresourceid

Comment: @Farrokh You said to use the correct id but this is written in the documentation..  ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)

Comment: @Farrokh And i have use "Activity" intead of "Context".Does it make any difference?

Comment: No problem, it work prerfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter):

> The id of the TextView within the layout resource to be populated

ArrayAdapters are commonly used in lists so a text resource id is included to display the item title. Passing 0 signifies the default state of no TextView resource.